# Converting multiple same name into one single name and also values get sum in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to fetch the  multi same name to single  name also sum  associated QTY values also.Show PART-ID as it's

example

[image]

I want to show like this

[image]

my controller

```
    public function productserach()
{ 
    $searchitem = Item_list::get();
    return view('products.product-serach',compact('searchitem'));
}
```

Comment: I'll give u a hint, select what you want to show and for qty add sum like this example [raw sum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) and double grouping for name and part-id like this example [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: @Gzai Kun can you post your answer

Comment: please try it first according to the instructions, and I will see your results and I will help to correct if it is not correct ;)

Comment: @Gzai Kun i checked documents but it making more confusing me please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('your_table')->select(DB::raw('sum(qty) as qty,name,part_id'))->groupBy('name','part_id')->get()
```

So basically use raw select to sum qty you want and group by fields that you want to have unique. Also you can use laravel eloquent like above but change it a bit because it is incorrect the output data will be not same as you want.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(qty)'

Comment: public function  totalproduct()
    {
          $totalproductlist =  DB::table('item_lists')->select('sum(qty) as qty,product_name,part_no')->groupBy('product_name','part_no')->get();
     
         return view('products.total-product',compact('totalproductlist'));
    }

Comment: @user12380208 Sorry forgot DB:raw please check answer

Comment: Forgot that laravel select expects array of values but not sql sum methods

Answer (score 1):

you can do try this code

```
use DB;

$sums = Model::select(DB::raw('sum(qty) as total_quantity'),'name')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Showing error syntax error, unexpected 'products' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: your code just makes multiple name in to single name other parts are not working ,qty and part_id

Comment: those row you want you have to kept in select parameter like if you want qty then after "name","qty"  .....put qty like these and you can keep your rest of the code